# Couldn't add two number in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i need to add two number using android kotlin what i tried so far i attached below. i am a beginner of android kotlin.

**txt3.text =  txt1.text.toString().toInt()+txt2.text.toString().toInt();**  this line i got the error was type dismatch

```
 val txt1 = findViewById(R.id.ed1) as EditText
        val txt2 = findViewById(R.id.ed2) as EditText
        val txt3 = findViewById(R.id.ed3) as EditText

        val btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1) as Button


        btn1.setOnClickListener{

            txt3.text = + txt1.text.toString().toInt()+txt2.text.toString().toInt();
```

i need to pass the total on txt3.text

Comment: txt3.text = String.valueOf(txt1.text.toString().toInt()+txt2.text.toString().toInt());

Comment: FYI - In Kotlin you rarely need `findViewById(...)`; you can just write `ed1` (and import Kotlin synthetic).

Comment: code plss sirddd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```
val val1 = txt1.text.toString().toInt()
val val2 = txt2.text.toString().toInt()
val val3 = txt3.text.toString().toInt()
val result = val1 + val2 + val3

txt3.setText(result.toString())
```

**N.B:** Use setText(String), since editText.text expects an Editable, not a String

Comment: txt3.text = result;  this line i got the error  type mismatch

Comment: Should use `result.toString()`

Comment: txt3.text = result.toString(); i used sir but still error is there

Comment: If not work then use this one `txt3.setText(result.toString())`

Comment: Check my updated answer. Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry last time I didn't checked in depth.

You can do it like this :

```
val valA = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.exitTextA).text.toString().toInt()

val valB = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.EditTextB).text.toString().toInt()

                findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textView).text.append((valA + valB).toString())
```

Comment: txt3.text = String.valueOf(txt1.text.toString().toInt()+txt2.text.toString().toInt()).toString();   i tried this unresolved reference